# Accessing parent class from Qt-derived objects

Tags: python, qt

In Qt, frequently it is necessary to create custom objects. For example, a `class myQLabel(QLabel):`. You will also likely pass the parent `QObject` to it's constructor and set it in the base class like so:

```
class bar(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
```

Given a situation such as the following:

```
class foo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        my_bar = bar(self)

    def baz():
        print("bazzed")
```

Is it appropriate to invoke the `baz` function within `my_bar` by calling `super().parent().baz()`.

Or, is it always preferred to defer to signals and slots. Begging the follow-up question, were this not Qt-based, would using parent in such a way be an appropriate way of calling a parent class's members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're confusing kinship between class(inheritance) and hierarchy between QObjects. In your case an instance of "foo", that is "self" is the parent of the instance "my_bar" but "foo" is not the parent of the class "bar".

Inheritance between classes is one of the main characteristics in OOP that allows to reuse code since it defines shared characteristics between classes. On the other hand, the hierarchy between QObject has memory management as its main task, that is, not having memory leaks.

With the above, making `super().parent().baz()` does not make sense since in this case `super().parent()` is the same as `self.parent()` since a getter is not override but you must use `self.parent().baz()`.

---

Now the design problem is attacked: If you use "self.parent().baz()" then you are forcing that any instance of "bar" must always have "foo" as its parent, and what happens if for some implementation the instance of "bar" is not necessarily going to be the child of the instance of "foo"? Well, you will have problems since with your design you do not give freedom. In conclusion, it will depend on whether your objective is to force any instance of "bar" to be a child of the instance of "foo".

To avoid these problems Qt implement the signals since they give us a lot of freedom, since it is notified (or invoked) to which method of a class X.

I recommend you read [Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) so that you understand the advantages of the signals over other elements such as callbacks, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! "kinship" was the word I was trying to find, but wasn't aware of